# insert usernames to database using comma's

Tags: php, mysql, flash, jquery-animate

i have a on line multi player game php mysql flash drivin,

i am getting winners player names via php and need to insert them to a db row
using comma's or a space between the names so that i may fetch it via php to display them in flash/animate.

here is the code that insert's to temp db row but only insert's one player name

```
if($user != ''){
 mysql_query("insert into ".DB_TEMPWINNER." (username,gameID) values('".$user."','".$gameID."')") or  die("could Not update");
}
```

$user being the players names to be inserted fetched above this code using php

if this is a bad way i could change it
i've experimented a bit and inserted each player name it's own row but was unable to send back to .swf to be displayed as it only displayed 1 player name when there was 2 for example.

I've been 6 years developing this game and try not to ask but this has had me baffled for roughly a year now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$arr = array("a", "b", "c");
$res = implode(",", $arr);
echo $res;
// a,b,c
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php to reverse